# C# reading sequentially text files from SSD drive is very slow the first time

Tags: c#, .net, caching, file-read

I am experiencing very slow sequential read of text files from SSD only the first time during a Windows session. Then the second and consecutive times reading is more than 60x faster (in second and subsequent run of the application, which means different Windows processes). I am pretty sure this is a normal consequence of system and/or SSD caching optimization but I ask a question here to double check this guess with the community because I didn't find anything by googling.

**Question: Can something be done to make the first time read faster?**

---

**Answer:**

I update this question since thanks to the @Alois Kraus answer we found the culprit which is Windows Defender file check upon file read!!

This Windows Defender slow check can be disabled through *Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection*. Under *Virus & threat protection settings*, select *Manage settings*, and then under *Exclusions*, select *Add an exclusions*. I can solve the peculiar issue either through *Folder Exclusion* (it works recursively under the folder) or *File Type*, and put the file extension(s) on which to disable slow check.

Now remain the questions:

- 1. how to detect programmatically Windows Defenders is slowing our code, so we can emit a warning to user and explain what to do
- 2. disable Windows Defender slow check programmatically (which I am pretty sure is impossible, else this would be a door opened for virus!)

[image: Windows Defender Exclusion]

---

**Details:**

I reproduce the issue on 2 distinct machines one with SAMSUNG SSD MZVLB1T0HALR 1TB (max read speed 3200MB/sec) one with SAMSUNG SSD MZVL21T0HCLR 1TB (max read speed 7000MB/sec).

With a classic `File.ReadAllText(filePathStr)` call I get the first time 33.555sec for 4.737 files (screenshot from dotTrace). All 4.7K text files cumulated weight 28MB on disk, this is less than 1MB read/sec.
[image]

Then second and subsequent time it is more than 60x faster, 540ms instead of 33sec, around 60MB read/sec (still very far from the SSD max read speed 3200MB/sec announced, but we read 4.7K files instead of just one).
[image]

---

I know `File.ReadAllText()` has some limitations (like assuming text file is UTF8 encoded which is ok in our context) so I tried something like:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePathStr);
long length = fileInfo.Length;
int bufferSize = length >= int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int)length;
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePathStr, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(
          fs, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize, false)) {
   content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   failureReason = null;
   return true;
}
```

...with same super slow performance the first time, and slower performance on second and subsequent times (853ms instead of 540ms):

[image]

---

Finally I did a test with this code:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePathStr);
string content = File.ReadAllText(filePathStr);
```

On first run I measured this, which advocates that this has nothing to do with text reading but only with file reading for the first time:

[image]

---

I did more tests on file read with Roslyn [`SourceReferenceResolver.ReadText(string resolvedPath):SourceText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.sourcereferenceresolver.readtext?view=roslyn-dotnet) and got the exact same result: 60x to 80x slower on 4.700 source files read  depending if it is performed first time after Windows boot or second or subsequent time (from 23sec to 270ms on the beefy new machine!). I guess if there was a way to achieve better performance Roslyn developers would have implemented it since they are both expert and so concerned with performances.

---

Some suggested to go async so I tried something like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach (string path in paths) {
      var task = File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
      tasks.Add(task);
}
foreach(var task in tasks) {
   string str = await task;
}
```

but results are same that by using `File.ReadAllText(path);`: same duration first time in Wnd session, same duration second and subsequent time in Wnd session.

Comment: Why do you need all content of those files? The boost is probably because of caching of the content and the memory allocations. If you need the data line by line, you should consider [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) and handle the file line by line.. this prevents reading the whole file.

Comment: Because of application data mine the content of those file. I am adding that we are talking of subsequent run of the application, which means different Windows processes.

Comment: Are you sure it is not because the computer is still doing other stuff right after booting? Does the problem persist if you boot the computer, wait half an hour, and *then* read the file?

Comment: @Jonash, I did the experiment on a beefy brand new machine and after waiting 30 minutes after Windows reboot exact same observation, first time slow, second time fast. Also I did the experiment immediately after Windows rebooting, same result. Also I did the experiment on another set of 4.000+ text file, same result.

Comment: That 3.2Gb/s is for *sequential* read. If you have that many files you will have a completely random read. I also suspect you will have a bunch of overhead in the OS for opening and keeping track of all the files. If you want good read performance you should probably try to keep fewer larger files. In some cases it *might* help putting all the files inside a zip-archive to help reduce overhead and keep reads sequential.

Comment: You also have memory allocation overhead in your app, and also the time it takes Windows to load up the MFT file allocation table.

Comment: @JonasH files are user files, we have no control over those, we just read those to data mine.

Comment: @Charlieface 28MB of text file allocation overhead? This is not much for a x64 process running on a beefy machine + that doesn't explain why the 2nd time is 60x faster. Also please read my comment above where we experimented waiting 30 minutes after Windows reboot, way enough time for MFT file allocation table unless it gets lazy initialized which could partly explain the 1st run slow and 2nd run 60x faster.

Comment: It's going to be at least double that, due to the way buffering works, and it's being allocated in very small chunks, so could still be slow (although that slow sounds unusual). As mentioned, using something like `ReadLinesAsync` might help. Lazy initialization of disk pages is the norm: there is no reason for Windows to read data it doesn't need, so the first run is always cold. Waiting 30 minutes will not help unless you force that folder info to be loaded. Try browsing the folder in File Explorer first maybe. Defragmenting the MFT might help also.

Comment: I updated the question with tests made with Roslyn source file reader code and obtain same results.  I guess if there was a way to achieve better performance, Roslyn developers would have implemented it since they are so concerned with performances.

Comment: Are all of these files within the same directory? If so, there'll be an overhead in filesystem indexing the files. We had a similar problem with and image resizer so we diced the files up into smaller directories. for example /files/fileone.txt would be moved to /files/f/fi/fileone.txt

Overall the complexity of the filesystem increased but it was miles faster at reading the files.

@PatrickfromNDependteam

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminJamesKippax no, those files are on the user machine and we don't have the possibility to re-organize those, our app just read those

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Yes, Samsung Is Swapping SSD Parts Too](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/samsung-is-swapping-ssd-parts-too),  [Samsung quietly revises 970 EVO Plus SSD with new Gen 4.0 controller](https://www.sammobile.com/news/samsung-quietly-revises-970-evo-plus-ssd-with-new-gen-4-0-controller/) and [MZVL21T0HCLR](https://www.techpowerup.com/ssd-specs/samsung-pm9a1-1-tb.d786) which shows the controller is: _Elpis (S4LV003)_

Comment: Are you attempting to open and read multiple files at the same time? If you are waiting for the previous file to close, before opening the next one, the OS cannot keep the disk busy by queueing multiple I/O requests. Of course once the OS has cached all files in memory, this idle time is less relevant.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman please read the title "C# reading **sequentially** text files", it is not at the same time

Comment: @user09938 thanks will do more test on non SAMSUNG SSD, one of the machine is pre covid and the other is post covid, if the problem comes from these specific hardwares the issue will be closed

Comment: Sure, you are currently reading each file in series. Which is why the first thing you should optimise is reading ahead. Even if that is only opening the file, reading a byte array, then waiting on a semaphore to continue processing the file data in series. You should be able to improve your code to the point that it is as fast as a windows file copy. Use that as your benchmark, to make sure you aren't aiming for anything impossible. But IMHO you won't see significant gains from reading the files in a different way, unless you read ahead.

Comment: Are the files processed in the same order between try 1 and tries 2-N?

Comment: Just to be sure, I will link the performance Rant. Particularly Part Two and Four are of relevance: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ | It can be fun to look for trivia every once in a while, just make sure you do not spend too much time on it.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to profile. But given that big slowdown it is most likely AV Scanner overhead. AV scanners tend to intercept file IO and scan the file contents which takes time.
To proof you need to start in an elevated command shell

```
wpr start CPU -start DiskIO -start FileIO
Run your test application or execute the use case from your already running application
wpr -stop c:\temp\SlowFileRead.etl
```

You can repeat that for the fast case again and name the file accordingly like `FastSecondRead.etl`

Wpr is part of Windows and works reliable since Win 11. For older OS you need to install the Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows SDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ the Win 11 WPT also works on Windows 10).

Then you can download ETWAnalyzer (I did write it) https://github.com/Siemens-Healthineers/ETWAnalyzer/releases and do

```
ETWAnalyzer -extract all -fd c:\temp\SlowFileRead.etl -symserver ms
cd c:\temp\Extract
ETWAnalyzer -dump CPU -pn YourAppName.exe -stacktags virus
```

Below is an example image how it will look like:
[image]

For more queries see help of ETWAnalyzer and this blog post:

- https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2022/03/22/how-fast-is-your-virus-scanner/

I have a small test application which creates 5K files and writes to them which is also very slow (sometimes) which is ETW profiling enabled to show what is influencing the performance:

- https://github.com/Alois-xx/FileWriter  (Test application written by me)
- The analysis of the data is here https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2022/07/25/pdd-profiler-driven-development/ which could be helpful how you should interpret the data.

Again this is definitely not SSD or file system cache related. To read 28 MB in 33 s you end up with 0.8 MB/s which is several magnitudes away from any SSD performance limit.

When ETWAnalyzer shows high defender wait times for your test process then you have found the issue. If not then you need to dump the methods and sort by wait time with

```
ETWAnalyzer -dump CPU -pn YourAppName.exe -methods *  -SortBy Wait -topNMethods 150
ETWAnalyzer -dump CPU -pn YourAppName.exe -methods *.sys;*.dll  -SortBy Wait -smi
```

The second query will display all device drivers and dlls which have no symbols which all AV scanners do not provide which is a good way to quickly identify new AV drivers from other vendors.

You can also export the data to csv by adding `-csv waitTimes.csv` and continue your analysis in Excel if you want to. I would check ReadFile/CreateFile/CloseHandle wait times and methods with similar wait times which are most likely part of the call stack. Then you will find the offending intercepting drivers or other things.
If you are checking for a specific driver version you can add `-smi` which is the shortcurt for `-ShowModuleVersion` to show module versions on each line quickly.

Antivirus is usually spending most time in CreateFile so I would start looking there first if you find a file system filter driver which intercepts your calls with similar timings.

To answer the question what you can do:

You can add an exclusion rule if your application is running elevated. For e.g. Defender you can add an exclusion rule via the powershell interface:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\temp\Test"
```

You can also ask the user to add an AV exclusion for your data files you are going to read to speed up things. This is a good thing anyway because build times go down the river if AV scanners are running on build directories where frequently new executables pop up and go away which is attracting AV scanners like a dead horse in the desert is attracting vultures.

***Update what you can do***

One possiblity is to do a self speed test with a known data set. You can e.g. create a folder in your target directory fill it with 5000 files and measure how long it takes. This will not test disk speed because the writes will be written async by the OS as long as the modified bytes are below a specific threshold. If you are much slower than you did anticipate you can issue a warning. The next step is to check the installed drivers in C:\Windows\System32\drivers. ETWAnalyzer knows practially all AV Drivers in its list: https://github.com/Siemens-Healthineers/ETWAnalyzer/blob/main/ETWAnalyzer/Configuration/WellKnownDrivers.json which you can also employ to pinpoint the user to create an exclusion for his AV solution. The problem is the drivers are used in different products and companies tend to aggregate and merge but the drivers remain.

Comment: Awesome thanks @Alois it looks promising, now off travelling for 2 weeks, cant wait to try check if antivirus is the root cause

Comment: @Alois Kraus This is an outstanding insight

Comment: Thanks @Alois Kraus, the culprit was indeed Windows Defender, I update the question to make this answer obvious! Now remain 1) how to detect programmatically Windows Defenders is slowing our code, so we can emit a warning to user and explain what to do 2) disable Windows Defender slow check programmatically (which I am pretty sure is impossible, else this would be a door opened for virus!)

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam: I have added some possibilities what you can do to check.

Comment: @AloisKraus if you could add some code or link to check if Wnd Defender slows down in your answer it would be awesome :)

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam: This is not so easy as it sounds. You can call into powershell to get excluded directories with Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExclusionPath but you need to do the pattern matching still by yourself. On the other hand Defender is just one AV solution so you then have just a solution for one AV. It is complicated.

Comment: We will investigate thanks @AloisKraus

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid to check the file length, reducing the operations to execute, thus the time to load the data, so you could remove this:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePathStr);
long length = fileInfo.Length;
int bufferSize = length >= int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int)length;
```

It makes sense to experiment with "reasonable" configurable values for the bufferSize (so you can tune it for each machine)  until you find the sweet spot.

Parenthesis: by my understanding the bufferSize should indeed be related only to the machine and would really impact only files bigger than the bufferSize. When the file is smaller it gets red to the end then it must be pushed to memory so there is no performance benefit from setting the bufferSize equal to the file length when the file is "small", it seems to me you do not have strict memory constraints as you are ready to allocate int.MaxValue as a buffer. On the other side, for "bigger" files, there will be "many" disk to memory writes, but the most adapt chunk size is related to the size of the memory bus and the disk characteristics. Yet I would need to backup this not only with my reasoning. Yet the previous suggestion still makes sense as you would reduce I/O.

You could also try to parallelize your code, if it is not already so, taking care in both cases to switch to the async pattern  using [ReadToEndAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamreader-readtoendasync) to better leverage the OS/Machine for parallel I/O operations, and find the sweet spot for the number of parallel reads that the disk/machine can handle.

```
var numParallelReads = 5;
var bufferSize = 4096;
var groupedPaths = paths.Select((path,idx) => (path, idx)).GroupBy(h => h.idx/numParallelReads);

foreach (var group in groupedPaths)
{
    var parallelPaths = group.Select(x => x.path);
    var tasks = parallelPaths.Select(p =>  {
       var sr = new StreamReader(p, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize);
       return sr.ReadToEndAsync().ContinueWith(x => { sr.Dispose(); });
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
}
```

Tweak the values of numParallelReads and bufferSize. If the size between the files varies a lot it COULD be worth ordering the reads to group together files in the same bucket size, so each batch uses the selected parallelization "most of the time"

Comment: I tried with File.ReadAllTextAsync() but obtain the same results (see updated question with this trial at the end of the question)

Comment: I would first find the average good bufferSize (4kb, 8kb..test and find sweetspot) and use it in the constructor of the SreamReader. Buffer size has a high impact on throughput.

Comment: for the parallelization you are not tuning the number of parallel reads, I'll add some code in my answer

Comment: Thanks can get at best 10% improvement with tuning parallelizing but that doesn't help for the bulk penalty the first time after OS reboot

Comment: the code I showed is quite "slim" and we are touching every "main" button: parallelize efficiently, use a bufferSize that fits the machine current configuration. I would say is worth checking if there are driver and firmware updates available

Comment: @david-ao: Before you optimize you should first find out what is slowing you down. See my answer how to find out if your file access pattern is really the issue here. Most likely it is not and simply AV overhead. Going multithreaded can get you into issues because parallel reads are a way to overload the system if AV is scanning in parallel multiplying CPU consumption on that machine. There exist ineffecient AV solutions which are serializing your reads during scanning nullifying your parallel reads ...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find out if caching is really happening, you should read the files bypassing the cache and try benchmarking it.

> On Windows you can disable buffering by passing FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag in FileOptions options parameter of stream constructor. There's no such value in FileOptions enum and you have to pass it's numerical value (0x2000000 - this value is found in FileStream source codes and is treated as valid).

```
FileStream readStream = new FileStream(
      path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, buffer, (FileOptions)0x20000000);
```

http://saplin.blogspot.com/2018/07/non-cachedunbuffered-file-operations.html

Comment: Thnaks, interesting, so for 47K source file read 33sec first time, 700ms second time, 1.600ms third time with (FileOptions)0x20000000. Wnd OS cache plays a role but it seems the bulk of first time read penalty comes from another cache (SSD cache?)

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam: Did you profile your system? A quick check in Task Manager Disk graph will show nearly 0 % disk utilization during the 33s. Why? Because Disk is not the issue here. See my answer how you can find out what is the actual issue.