# Reducing the time needed to gather files from a larger amount of directories

Tags: c#, .net, performance, winforms

Hiho.

I'm not sure if it is possible to decrease loading times in my program, or if I just have to switch to SSDs. But maybe someone has an Idea :)

I'm getting the first (max) 100 files from a large number of folders and write their path to a single list. The problem is that it takes ages to load this list because I always get the whole content of the folder to a temporary list and then write the first 100 entries of that temporary list to my final list. Maybe it is faster if I could skip this extra step but I'm not sure if this is possible and if this would make any difference.

My code looks like this:

```
foreach (string Folder in FolderList)
{
    List<string> FileListTMP = new List<string>();
    FileListTMP.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Folder));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < FileListTMP.Count && i < 100)
    {
        FileList.Add(FileListTMP[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

It would be great if there is a solution to my problem because the number of folders is always growing and the loading times are already around 20 seconds long. :)

**More info:** At this time there are around 1500 folders. There are not more than 1000 files in a single folder. The average is about 500 files per folder.

Comment: You can use [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles) instead of `GetFiles`, like `FileList.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder).Take(100))`.

Comment: How many files has each folder on average and at maximum? How many are the folders?

Comment: As usual you should profile. Using EnumerateFiles might help but you should also check out the Antivirus overhead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012101/c-sharp-reading-sequentially-text-files-from-ssd-drive-is-very-slow-the-first-ti/76062486#76062486 for an example. You might be surprised where your actual bottleneck is.

Comment: There are not more than 1000 files in a single folder. I guess the average is about 500 files per folder. At this time there are around 1500 folders.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. With using EnumerateFiles and .Take(100) I could decrease the loading time to under 8 seconds. I also included a logic that reduces the files I get from a single folder based on the amount of folders, with this the loading time is most of the time under 5 seconds (as far as i could verify this in the last hour). I'll test a bit more but it looks quite good now. :)

Comment: Do you have permission to write and rename these files? If so, I suggest creating a function that generates the path based on the file name, so you can index in ascending order and get that file on time. Example: `public string GetFullPathFile(string path, int fileName)` => ` GetFullPathFile("C:\\TestDir", 999)` => `C:\TestDir\1\1\1\999.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code is directly equivalent to

```
FileList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Folder).Take(100));
```

But the only thing that should take significant time in that piece of code is the `GetFiles`-call. Moving things between lists can be a problem if you are processing many millions of items, but should not be an issue when talking about hundreds of items. But you should use a performance profiler to verify this assumption, perhaps there is something completely different that takes time.

You could try changing `.GetFiles` to `.EnumerateFiles` since the later returns an enumerable rather than an array, so might be faster if you do not need a complete list of all files.

In my experience it might also be possible to get a performance speedup when listing files by using the native API rather than `GetFiles`. Something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256522/12342238). But it does require a decent chunk of somewhat complex code.

Comment: Thank you. EnumerateFiles decreases the loading time from about 20 seconds to a bit over 15. It's better than nothing :)